# UDP receive ignores broadcast from own address

Tags: linux, sockets, networking, udp, broadcast

I'm having what I believe to be a strange repeatable behavior.  I have an isolated network.  At startup, several embedded Linux devices will start with the same IP address.  The idea was to have them use UDP broadcast to send an identification packet, with a unique identifier, and then they could sort out their addresses.  However, what I am seeing is that each device can receive its own broadcast packet, but it will not receive broadcast packets from other devices with the same IP address.  There are no issues receiving broadcast packets from devices that already have assigned, non-conflicting addresses.  I've tested the code with a mix of embedded Linux devices and Linux PC's but the result is the same.  Broadcast reception only works if sent from an address that is not your own.  Is there some lower level network limitation at play.

Below is the code for the socket setup

```
  sintn sn_broadcast_listen_socket_create(void)
  {
     sintn sn_sckt;
     struct sockaddr_in t_me;

     mt_own_address.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
     ms16_print_addresses(AF_INET, OUR_INTERFACE, TRUE, &mt_own_address);

     sn_sckt = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP);
     if (sn_sckt < 0)
     {
        printf("sn_broadcast_listen_socket_create-socket:(%d)%s\n", errno, strerror(errno));
     }
     else
     {
        memset(&t_me, 0, sizeof(t_me));
        t_me.sin_family = AF_INET;
        t_me.sin_port = htons(MODBUS_IP_PORT);
        t_me.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);

        if (bind(sn_sckt, (struct sockaddr*)&t_me, sizeof(t_me)) < 0)
        {
           printf("sn_broadcast_listen_socket_create-bind:(%d)%s\n", errno, strerror(errno));
           sn_sckt = -1;
        }
     }

     return sn_sckt;
  }

  sintn sn_broadcast_socket_create(void)
  {
     sintn sn_mysocket;
     sintn broadcastEnable = TRUE;

     sn_mysocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP);
     if (sn_mysocket < 0)
     {
        printf("sn_broadcast_socket_create-socket:(%d)%s\n", errno, strerror(errno));
     }
     else if (setsockopt(sn_mysocket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_BROADCAST, &broadcastEnable, sizeof(broadcastEnable)) < 0)
     {
        printf("sn_broadcast_socket_create-setsockopt:(%d)%s\n", errno, strerror(errno));
        sn_mysocket = -1;
     }

     return sn_mysocket;
  }


  sint16 s16_broadcast_send(sintn osn_bsocket, uint32 ou32_address, uint16 ou16_port, T_modbus_adu *opt_mb_adu, uint16 ou16_size)
  {
     struct sockaddr_in t_other;
     sint16 s16_rval = C_NO_ERR;


     memset(&t_other, 0, sizeof(t_other));
     t_other.sin_family = AF_INET;

     t_other.sin_port = htons(ou16_port);
     t_other.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(ou32_address);

     if (sendto(osn_bsocket, opt_mb_adu, ou16_size, 0, (struct sockaddr*)&t_other, sizeof(t_other)) < 0)
     {
        printf("s16_broadcast_send-sendto:(%d)%s\n", errno, strerror(errno));
        s16_rval = C_UNKNOWN_ERR;
     }

     return s16_rval;
  }
```

The receive is triggered by a read select() on the socket.  The send destination address is INADDR_NONE.  Like I said before, everything works as long as the broadcast sender and the broadcast receiver have different IP addresses.

Comment: I'm not optimistic that this is possible to do reliably at the application level -- most likely either switch's ARP table gets confused by the duplicate IP addresses, or the boxes themselves ignore the incoming packets from "their own" IP address.  Any chance that you could install dhcpd or avahid instead?  They are designed to handle this sort of thing...

Comment: One other thing you could do, if your devices support IPv6, is use IPv6 multicast packets (sent to eg ff12::somewellknownaddress) to communicate.  Since every ipv6-enabled device has a unique link-local IPv6 address based on its MAC address, there is no chicken-and-egg problem preventing IPv6 communication between uninitialized devices.

Comment: It appears that the issue is local to the box.  I have three boxes, only two share the same IP.  The box with the unique IP can see all broadcasts and can identify them as they come from different ports.  The two boxes that share the same IP only see their own broadcasts.  I just provided a networking framework for a customer.  I never expected the framework to be used in this way.  I was trying to determine if I could provide the customer the functionality that they want at the application level, or just tell them they will have to work around the issue, as it is not possible.  Thanks..